# Is there a way to copy an ibm cloud function from one account to another

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function in an account that might be deleted one day. How can I move/copy this function into another account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Command Line Interface (CLI) for IBM Cloud Functions has a "[action get](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-cli-plugin-functions-cli#cli_action_get)" command. There are some parameters to obtain the action code as well as to save it to a file.

If you know the action, save it from account A, then deploy it to account B. If there are more, use the list commands for namespaces, packages and actions to obtain the action names.